# How to focus on label(s) that is(are) difficult to predict?

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification

I am facing with binary classification problem. I am using some machine learning models and Python 3. I have noticed that some models perform better on a given class than the others. I would like to combine them to improve my accuracy and precision. I know a way to do so in regression problems, something like a weighted average of predictions. But I am not sure that it makes sense in classification problem. And, you must know a better way to do so.

Here is my algorithm that helps me to identify labels which are particularly difficult to predict :

```
"""
each value is in {0, 1}
ytrue : real values
ypred : predicted values
"""
def errorIdentifier(ytrue, ypred):
    n = len(ytrue)
    ytrue = list(ytrue)
    ypred = list(ypred)
    error = [0,0]
    for i in range(n):
        if ytrue[i] != ypred[i] :
            error[ytrue[i]] += 1
    return error
```

As you can guess, I need to call it for each model I am using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue that different models are better are predicting different class is a classical machine learning problem. It arises due to the fact the various algorithms are better at modelling different features, hence the inclination towards better accuracy on a certain class.

To overcome this issue, we can make use of a number of models and **ensemble** the results to get an improved accuracy. This approach is known as [ensemble learning](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Ensemble_learning).

There are a number of methods such as `bagging`, `boosting` etc. and some well known ensemble learning algorithms such as `RandomForest`. You'll have to research the various techniques to find the one that best suits your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know bagging and boosting. But, what I would like is to combine models that I want to combine. RandomForest does ensemble learning based on decision tree, and the bagging classifier of sklearn does the same but you can choose the algorithm(base estimator). It doesn't fit my wish. I would like to do ensemble learning by using models such as SVM, Neural Networks, XGBoost. But may be I am wrong... Do you have an idea ?

Comment: Yes you can stack your own models. Here's a good example for [stacking models](http://blog.kaggle.com/2016/12/27/a-kagglers-guide-to-model-stacking-in-practice/). Also you can make use of meta algorithms such as AdaBoost with your own models.

Comment: Thank you for the example, I think that idea is brilliant ! let's see whether it gives good results :)